# Error log in to help salesforce

Tags: error, login, help

Maybe this is not the place to ask this.

In a Production org, I try to open the link of Help, but it takes me to this two URL before log me out in the help.salesforce.org page.

htauthprovidererrorhandler?ErrorCode=REGISTRATION_HANDLER_ERROR&ErrorDescription=Script-thrown+exception&ProviderId=AnId&startURL=%2Fapex%2Fhtdoor%3Flanguage%3Des%26release%3D224.22.3%26instance%3DUM1
Help_Home?err=1&siteLang=es

I tried in different navigators (Firefox and Chrome), but it still log me out in the Help page.

I can log to the help page with this org before, so I don't know what's happening now.

Thanks

Comment: Definitely contact support (email support @ salesforce.com) for assistance. This error generally indicates an error in the server, one we likely cannot fix.

Comment: I tried to login to the trailhead page with the user from the org and worked.